# Struts 2 text box arrangment

Tags: struts2

I want to create a form that contains text boxes as follow. I am using Struts2.

```
User Name
|Text Box for user name|

mail id
|Text box for mail id|    

<s:textarea name="username" id="username" label="User Name"/>
```

This is showing:

```
User name |Text Box for user name|
```

But I want the above format. When I am using validation framework label is shown in italic, I want normal text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because of default struts2 theme factor xhtml which is showing the output html in table structure
Change the theme to simple ans use your own css/HTML way to customize the output

crate a struts.properties file and add the following entry

```
struts.ui.theme=simple
```

this will change the theme for whole application as struts2 tags will no longer generates HTML/table code for you

else u can override the theme per page basis 
like

```
<s:set name="theme" value="'simple'" scope="page" />
```

alternate way can be what "Steven" suggested

Comment: The less files the better, putting constants in struts.xml keeps the file list down... and with conventions there shouldn't be much in there anyways (just add: <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple"/> right after <struts>).

Comment: agree!!! that is also a good thing but some how i am of the mind set to put such configuration things in property file,but that is just a matter of taste.

Comment: I used to prefer the properties file too, but Quaternion converted me to the struts.xml approach for constants. I rarely ever create the properties file anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You're in luck. Just add the `labelposition="top"` attribute to your Struts2 input tags. e.g.,

```
<s:textfield name="subject"
             label="Subject"
             size="30"
             maxlength="50"
             labelposition="top"
             required="true"/>
```

As for the italic label, that should be controlled by CSS.